# how to convert 3012944070 to (301) 294-4070 using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to convert the phone number to international phone number example

```
 3012944070 Output will be like this (301) 294-4070
```

Comment: Post what you have tried  so far please.

Comment: you can try it with jquery instead of rails framework, check the link http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/3/

Comment: Define "international phone number" format, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the built in helper http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone I believe it outputs in US only

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub`:

```
phone = 3012944070
phone.to_s.sub(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '(\1) \2-\3')
# => "(301) 294-4070"
```